# what is the difference between simple item animation and predictive animation for recyclerview?

Tags: android

this is the note in the recyclerview.java:

“Predictive item animations” are automatically created animations that show where items came from, and where they are going to, as items are added, removed, or moved within a layout.

“simple item animations”, whose position are changing are simply faded in/out

what I want to known is the difference between both. For example, adapter trigger a item move from position 0 to position 3, then the items in the position 1/2/3 will move forward one position. The animation for the items(1,2,3) is predicitive animation?